# AJAX how to call $ajax() error: function from django

Tags: django, ajax, django-views

I am a beginner in web development. I am trying to make a website that has like a comment module where the user can like the comment and updating total upvotes using ajax. But somehow ajax error function is not getting called even when error. only the success function is getting called no matter what. I don't know how to make it work

here is ajax code:

```
function upvotecomment(postid, commentid, votes_total){

$('#upvotingcmt').one('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(event)
  console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
  upvotingcomment(postid, commentid, votes_total);
});
}

function upvotingcomment(postid, commentid, votes_total) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "upvotecomment/"+postid+"/"+commentid, // the endpoint
        type : "POST", // http method

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            votes_total += 1;
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            $('#totalupvotes').text(votes_total);
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the 
            error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

here is Django view function:

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/signup")
def upvotecomment(request, post_id, comment_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = post_id)
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk = comment_id)
        response_data = {}
        if comment.user.username == request.user.username:
            messages.error(request, "Commenter can't upvote their own comment !")
            return redirect('creators')  
        else:
            try:
                vote = Commentvote.objects.get(commentID=comment, postID=post, userID=request.user)
                messages.error(request, 'You have already voted for this comment!')
                return redirect('creators')
            except Commentvote.DoesNotExist:
                vote = None
                # find product by id and increment
                post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
                # find comment by id and increment
                comment = Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
                vote = Commentvote(commentID=comment, postID=post, userID=request.user)
                comment.votes_total += 1
                vote.save()
                comment.save()

                response_data['result'] = 'upvoted successfully!'

                return HttpResponse(
                    json.dumps(response_data),
                    content_type="application/json"
                )
            else:
                return HttpResponse(
                    json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
                    content_type="application/json"
                )
```

I am using ajax function for handling csrf token which is working fine.

Comment: What error is being returned that is not triggering the error callback?

Comment: It is not returning any error. just increasing the votes_total and updating it on the DOM and then showing success. i.e running the success: function . and because of the return redirect in my view function the Json seems to print the whole page on the console again. I don't know what to do there so that the error function will be called

Comment: A redirect is not an "error". You need to return an error response code (40x for example) to trigger the error callback

Answer (score 1):

Return the errorMessage to output in your dev console

```
     error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
         // error callback
         console.log(errorMessage);
         }
```

But this is not the reason why its always returning no error message. Its because the jquery AJAX call is successful. Thats what it determines and just that. So, Django is receiving it and the function you are calling is working via AJAX, so my suggestion is to rather handle the supposed error in the success function with looking something up that you've returned back from django. Also rather work with JSONResponse and return a dict. In the dict can be your argument. You might want to return a http500 or http404 and that should output it in your ajax error function

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a proper `status_code` to trigger the `error callback` in frontend, for example

```
def upvotecomment(request):
    ...
    message: 'Permission denied'
    status_code = 403
    # JsonResponse is just a wrapper of HttpResponse, with context_type set to application/json and return a JSON-encoded response.
    return JsonResponse({'message':message }, status=status_code)
```

Comment: will the httpresponsubclass work?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-subclasses

Comment: @naveen Yeah, `status` is keyword argument in the `HttpResponseBase`, so any `HttpReponse` subclass including  `JsonResponse`  can set `status` in the views.